# Kali linux persistence mouse/keyboard failure

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, kali-linux

I'm using a 2015 MacBook pro and have had no issues whatsoever before using an external mouse and keyboard. However, as soon as I connect a mouse and keyboard, the issues begin.

During the session, there are no problems; however, upon reboot into persistence from the boot menu, no mouse, hardware or external or bluetooth or otherwise, function properly.

If "live" or any other mode is selected from the boot menu, there are no problems. Additionally, "persistence" is accessible from these boot modes so I'm able to edit (as far as I can see) the files used in persistence.

Please advise on how to continue to resolve this problem. I have reflashed the drive 10 times to replicate this problem and I'm sure this **is** the problem.

I have installed persistence straightforward like this:

```
    mkdir -p /mnt/KALI
    
    mount /dev/sdc3 /mnt/KALI
    
    echo "/ union" > /mnt/KALI/persistence.conf
    
    umount /mnt/KALI
```

I'm pretty sure the problem only occurs after using an external mouse and keyboard; however it doesn't matter if I reboot with them plugged in or not.

**EDIT1:**

- Laptop: MacbookPro petin 13" early 2015
- Keyboard: A1243
- Mouse: M/N:N910U
- USB: PNY16GB
- Kali: 2018.1-amd64.iso

I've been having the recent problem of my keyboard/mouse, hardware or external, not functioning whatsoever after entering persistence mode in Kali.

The steps taken to reproduce the issue are simple.

**with or without keyboard/mouse plugged in:**

- apt-get update
- reboot -h now

*normal functionality*

**with keyboard/mouse plugged in, or even after unplugging keyboard/mouse before executing reboot:**

- apt-get upgrade
- reboot -h now

*unable to use either hardware trackpad/keyboard or external mouse/keyboard*

Which logs can I grab off of the persistence partition to post here?
I'm at a loss of what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey from what I've found your headers probably broke during the update. So just reinstall your headers and you should probably be good.
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

If that works let me know, my surface is suffering from the same issue and I believe that is the case. I'm relatively new to Kali so I could very well be wrong though.

Comment: I've been thinking you're on to something, but I'm unable to use any keyboard after this happens. A more detailed work-around for this editing directories directly inside of the USB flash drive mounted in another operating system is required.